# How to deform a material with nodes

Tags: texturing, materials, uv, node-editor, geometry-nodes

I want to place a text on a mesh that has the shape of a branch. the text is embedded in a material. is there a way to deform the text with nodes so that it fits exactly, like in the reference? thanks!

[image: Reference]

[image: Material in Blender]

[Blend File](https://we.tl/t-5hO8bGMo0d)

Comment: did you play with the scale and rotation values in mapping node? if that doesn't help, please provide blend file

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simplest way to do it is to use the *UV Texture Coordinate* output rather than the *Generated* output. Unwrap your object in order to get a square UV (for example with the *Follow Active Quads* mode) and the text will follow the shape:

[image]

As your topology is a bit messy, what you can do is first unwrap with the *Project From View* option, in the *Shader Editor* choose the *Texture Coordinate UV* output, and choose the *Extend* option of the *Image Texture* node:

[image]

Now in the *UV Editor* enable the *Proportional Editing* option, select some vertices and begin to straigthen the UV manually with some move/rotate/scale:

[image]

You should get something like that:

[image]

Comment: +1 but obviously you did take the wrong text, wrong font, wrong color...so i don't know whether you got a check for that...

Comment: sorry I didn't have the Chris logo  :/

Comment: no problem, give me you address, i will send it via UPS to you, so you can scan it with your 3D scanner...

Comment: @Chris Hello! I have edited the question and put the link down below. I really appreciate your help! thanks.

Comment: @ Christoph, I've edited my answer, I hope it helps

Comment: @Christoph: Moonboots answer is right of course. He has a phenomenal knowledge of Blender. But i don't want to steal his "check" for the right answer because he was the first and i just could say the same...maybe with more details explained...but...i made a video so can you follow step by step how you can do it. I hope this helps you. Link: https://youtu.be/UhFBiz0Wb1Y.  The quality will get better - HD is still uploading.

Comment: @moonboots you and Chris are just incredible! hope some day Im gonna be as skilled as you two! thank you so much.

Comment: @Chris just insane! thank you so much for your effort!

Comment: @Christoph: wir Namensvettern müssen doch zusammenhalten ;) Gern geschehen.